# How to build a membership comparison overview?

Tags: css

I have a bit of an unusual question, but I'm stuck and thought someone here may know. I basically want to create a membership overview/comparison as included and was wondering how one would build it most efficiently/best, especialyl the part highlighted in red.

[image]

***Would you tackle it with CSS and build each single element? Or would you rather do it in photoshop and include such pictures via code e.g. as background image?***

Given that it's still code related (i.e. is it possible / efficient to build this with CSS), I hope the question is valid and someone could shed some light onto this! ***(I dont expect any code solution at all, just would like to understand if CSS/SVG coding is the most efficient way).***

Thanks a lot for any help!!

Comment: hmmm, the question is not valid and you will get some downvote i guess ... but yes this can be done with CSS ;) a bit tricky but doable

Comment: Thanks Temani! Should I rather delete then? I know you have lots of experience, would you say it is most efficient with CSS or would it typically rather be done with photoshop? I'm just not sure what the most efficient way would be to tackle it

Comment: here is an idea https://jsfiddle.net/2cm43sLb/7/ .. for me it can be easily done with CSS so need to complicate with SVG or photoshop :)

Comment: unbelievable Temani!! I will analyse the code to understand and tailor for my need! Dont know how to thank you - I wasnt even expecting any code solution! thank you so much!!! Please post it as answer so I can vote and close! Thanks a million!

Comment: Just to understand further, I assume you could also do this half circle with a div and 50% border radius and then make it relative position with a z-index lower than the "Gold Member" area to position it behind?

Comment: or instead of a div a pseudo element with a dashed border and radius to 50% ;) and yes play with Z-index ... concerning my code simply change the colors of each gradient to see them and you will understand :) the magic is when they all have same color to create the shape ;)

Comment: Makes sense re pseudo! Good hint to change the colour, will definitely make it easier! What I'm most unfamiliar with is the code you have after the bracket "100% 100%/50% 20px". I though initially this would be the gradient colour stops, but these are already in the brackets - what is the code after the brackets, it looks like it's sizing the gradient within the div?

Comment: `background-position-x background-position-y/height width` --> shortly `background-position/background-size` ... maybe you are more familiar with such thing `center/cover`

Comment: incredibly helpful! Now I can tailor it as needed! Thank you so much, really!!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a single SVG element and just reuse it across the three different columns, changing the fill (orange/gray/blue).

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look into an SVG solution and check if this could be most efficient!

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to use bootstrap to reach this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <!-- Column one, detail list -->
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <!-- Column two, first membership option -->
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <!-- Column third, second membership option -->
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <!-- Column four, third membership option -->
</div>
</div>
```

you'll get a responsive well designed behaviour:

https://jsfiddle.net/zzhs5w6n/2/

The part that you marked in red are only images.
You can find some for free googling a bit, or you can design yourself using photoshop, illustrator, or even gimp or microsoft paint if you want.
Then, in the example, you must add responsiveness to this images, check the next complete fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/zzhs5w6n/10/

Then, you can add more bootstrap css or your main css to adapt it to whatever you want/need.

Hope it helps